# Php Foreach to arraylist

Tags: php, foreach

I would like to learn how to set arraylist with for each to new list

Example :

```
$client_ids = array (
'id1',
'id2',
'id3'
)
```

When i print it it shows

```
Array ( [0] => id1 [1] => id2 [2] => id3 )
```

i need to change it as like as

```
    array (
    [0] array(
              'type' => 'client_id',
                'value' => 'id1'
            ),
    [1] array(
              'type' => 'client_id',
                'value' => 'id2'
            ),
    [2] array(
              'type' => 'client_id',
                'value' => 'id3'
            )
);
```

how can i do it ?
i can write them as like as second list but i have a 50 client_id and it will makes everthing difficult,
cuz Weekly i am changing id list

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Is the text 'client_id' static or you take the data from another array. This seems to be a simple task, so we want you to try to solve it yourself first.

Comment: Yes, i tried i am  senior front end developer and really new on php also backend.

Comment: What did you try? Give us something to work with!

Comment: The solution is a two-liner. Start by using foreach to cycle through $client_ids.

Comment: `array_walk($client_ids, function (&$value) { $value = ['type' => 'client_id', 'value' => $value]});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it out here http://viper-7.com/t5eAmg

```
<?php
$client_ids = ['id1','id2','id3'];
$newarray = [];
foreach($client_ids as $key => $value) {
    array_push($newarray,["type" => "client_id", "value" => $value,]);
}
print_r($newarray);
?>
```

Comment: i tried this

<?php
$client_ids = array (
        'id 1',
        'id 2',
        'id 3',
    );


foreach ($client_ids as $index=>$value ) {
 $client_ids[]= array (
     'type' => 'client_id',
     'value'=> $value
    );
}
print_r ($client_ids);

Comment: And what happened ? I copied and pasted what you responded, and it worked fine. You need to explain what did not work.

Comment: Your code works great thank you friend,
Mine was creating something interesthing

Comment: ok great. You could also use array_walk as mark suggested. I only used foreach because you tagged that in your post.

Comment: There array_walk is a little slower, but for your 50 it will not be noticeable.

Comment: Thank you friend i would like to learn true way to do them and now 2 way really thank you